# Excel VBA - Enter starting and ending day into a calendar

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to come up with an idea on how to write a VBA script which will scan certain columns for starting dates of projects and put the day in the respective cell in a calendar. To make things clearer here's a basic look at what it should look like:

[image: What it should look like]

As you can see the calendar contains the months as well as the days every new week begins (Mondays). For example: The project in line 4 starts on April 10th 2017. The script should scan that cell and fill in D4 with a 10. The project in line 5 starts on May 3rd so it should fill in G5 with the value 3. The same for all other lines and ending dates as well.

So far I had the idea to let the macro scan every cell and compare it to every possible entry in 2017 (i. e. every day of the year). That would look a little something like this:

```
    destiny_row = 1
    For x = 2 To MaxRowList
    If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1), "10.04.2017") > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("$D$" & x).Value = "10"
        destiny_row = destiny_row + 1
    End If
    Next
```

But as you can imagine this would be quite some piece of code one would have to write as you would have to write it for every day of the year and then copy it for ending dates and it wouldn't be very efficient.

Does anybody have an idea how this could be done in a smart way? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

***EDIT1:***
So, I have tried to implement what was mentioned in the comments as good as I could. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Example4()
Dim objDate1 As Date
Dim objDate2 As Date
Dim objDate3 As Date
Dim runningVB As Boolean


If IsDate(Cells(4, 1)) = True Then
objDate1 = CDate(Cells(4, 1))
Else
MsgBox ("Invalid Input")
Exit Sub
End If

If IsDate(Cells(2, 4)) = True Then
objDate2 = CDate(Cells(2, 4))
Else
MsgBox ("Invalid Input")
Exit Sub
End If

If IsDate(Cells(2, 5)) = True Then
objDate3 = CDate(Cells(2, 5))
Else
MsgBox ("Invalid Input")
Exit Sub
End If


If objDate1 < objDate2 Then
Cells(4, 3) = objDate1
Else
End If
If objDate1 < objDate2 Then
runningVB = True
Else
End If

If runningVB = True Then
End
Else
End If

If objDate1 < objDate3 Then
Cells(4, 4) = objDate1

Else
End If
If objDate1 < objDate3 Then
runningVB = True
Else
End If

If runningVB = True Then
End
Else
End If


End Sub
```

I have written it for comparing only to D2 and E2 so far but it works. Is there any easier way to go about this? Any way with simpler code? Because this way I still would have to write it for every starting day of every week of the year.

Comment: Change the row with the days of the month to actual dates that are formatted to only display the day, `d`.  The you can find where the date is fits with `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match()`

Comment: Consider using formulas instead, VBA is not needed here.

Comment: @avb How would I go about using formulas? Only thing that comes to my mind is to let formaulas "scan" for each day as well but that wouldn't be very smart. Is there a formula which would help in this case?

Comment: Again only works if you put dates in row 2 that are formatted to show only the day.  Then you can use MATCH() to find the column in which it fits then compare that to the column in which the formula is.

Comment: Convert values in second row to real dates, then check if that date is between values in A:B cells, if so, and the cell to the left is not between you got start cell. Per analogiam you can find the end. I do not insist for not using VBA, particularly if you have some code in that workbook already, but if you don't....

Comment: Could you guys check the edit I made in my initial post?

Comment: Please check if understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be helpful. But there will be huge changes to your worksheet

**1)** if you want to see other dates you can change [A1] - in green highlight.

**2)** copy and paste the formulas below. For **RED** `=$A1+COLUMN()-3`, for **BLUE** `=MID(TEXT(C2,"mmmm"),TEXT(C2,"d"),1)`.

**3)** You can input start and end date in their respective column.

[image]

And use this code.

```
Sub Example4()

' Setting up the worksheet
Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Set wsActive = ActiveSheet
wsActive.Cells.Interior.Color = 16777215

' Variables we will use to loop through your sheet
Dim iCell As Integer

' Variables we will use to color your sheet
Dim iDistance As Integer
Dim iStart As Integer

With wsActive
  ' Looping through your sheet
  For iCell = 3 To .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    iStart = .Cells(iCell, 1) - .Cells(1, 1)
    If Not iStart < 0 Then
      iDistance = .Cells(iCell, 2) - .Cells(iCell, 1)
      .Range(.Cells(iCell, iStart + 3), .Cells(iCell, iStart + iDistance + 3)).Interior.Color = 65535 '<~ change this to desired color
        iStart = 0
        iDistance = 0
        GoTo NextItem
      End If
NextItem:
  Next
End With
End Sub
```